# Automatic Screen Shots with specific banner ads

Tags: screenshot, screen-scraping, google-dfp

I manage a website that serves banner ads using Google DFP.

A couple customers have been asking for daily screen-shots of the website which show thier ad in place. While most advertisers are happy with a report showing impressions/clicks, a couple are demanding the screen shots.

I have found a few tools that can get a screen shot from a specific page on a scheduled basis. I am running into 2 problems with most of these...

1) The "screen shot" does not always reflect what the site looks like after all of the javascript has applied. I need to wait until the javascript finishes before the screen shot is saved

2) I rotate mulitple ads into positions. I do not have a way to control which ad appears when the screen shot is taken.

Is this a common request to get?

Has anyone come up with an honest solution to either of these questions?

Comment: Have you tried some Screenshot services? Browshot (https://browshot.com/) does this for advertisers, I'm sure other services offer it too. If you use a carousel or accordion, you can inject JavaScript to control the position, or you can take multiple screenshots of the same page to see each position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use irobotsoft tool.  Go to your website, then use:

CapturePage(filename)

to capture the page into an image file.  You can let it capture on a fixed schedule, or test the ad content before capturing.